# How to count the number of rows in the tables. (RSpec, Capybara)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this code:

```
<table class="table" id="charges_failed">
<tr>
  <th>Customer</th>
  <th>Charge Amount</th>
  <th>Date Failed</th>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
<% @charges_failed.each do |charge| %>
  <tr bgcolor="#FF0000">
    <td><%= charge.formatted_customer_name %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(charge.amount.to_s) %></td>
    <td><%= charge.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

And I have this test:

```
it "check failed charges" do
  visit root_path
  expect(page).to have_selector('table#charges_failed tr', :count => 6)
end
```

Why he finds only the first row in the table. Total on page 6 of them.
(error: expected to find css "table#charges_failed tr" 6 times, found 1 match: "Customer Charge Amount Date Failed")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find the easiest method is to use xpaths.

Would be something like:

```
within('table#charges_failed') do
    expect(page).to have_xpath(".//tr", :count => 6)
end
```

You could probably also drop the 'within' and define a full xpath like: *".//table[@id='charges_failed']//tr"*

As far as I know have_selector just checks for the presence of something (css, xpath etc).  I've never seen a count used with it before.

Answer (score 5):

You can also write the following check:

```rb
within('#charges_failed') do
  expect(all('tr').count).to eq(6)
end
```

This will check that your table has exactly 6 rows